# Logo looks pixelated when saved as PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, png

Heyo - I saved a logo on illustrator as PDF and it looks normal when I view it on both a mobile phone and a laptop. When I save it as a PNG and view it on a laptop it looks fine but when I view it on my phone, it looks really pixelated/liney. Any help would be much appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXRGh.jpg)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add more details? what are your PNG export settings? are you resizing the image before exporting? After exporting? Is the background part of the PNG file or not?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are you viewing the image at 1:1 (100%) on your phone? To be fair, if you zoom in on a raster image you shouldn't be surprised if you can see pixels.

Comment: Are you making a PNG file directly from illustrator or are you converting it from a PDF first and then converting to a PNG?
Try going directly out of illustrator, and make sure you have antialiasing turned on.

Answer (score -1):

A pdf file or an illustrator file uses vectors, this means you can enlarge them to any size and it will look fine. A png is a bitmap file, this means its made up of individual pixels. Decide how big it needs to be (in pixels) then export to that size.

The illustrator export has some options to do this, you can also open the illustrator file in photoshop, which tells you the pixel size in the open dialog. There's a number of guides on exporting online if you search.

Comment: Corrected a typo - where i put that a pdf was a bitmap file, rather than png. Other than that - this is quite probably the issue. Not sure the typo deserved the downvote though!